# Complex navigation in React Native using react-navigation and Redux

Tags: react-redux, react-native, react-navigation

I have the following navigation structure in my React Native app:

`StackNavigator` configured with 3 routes:

1. Splash screen (React Component)
2. `StackNavigator` for my login flow
3. `DrawerNavigator` for my core app screens.

The `DrawerNavigator` has some dynamic multiple routes, but also one static route which is another `StackNavigator`.
Everything seems to be working as expected:

1. The store is being updated accordingly.
2. Navigation between screen works.
3. Go back between screen works when configured within each component, with the following command:

   ```
   this.props.navigation.goBack();
   ```

My question is - is there a way for me to handle back button on Android globally? Currently when I click on the back button, nothing happens (due to the fact I'm using Redux). Should I handle the back button in each component or is there a way of doing it using Redux?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but there is a way to handle this with redux. In your `index.js` file where you create your store you can make export a class and add a `componentWillMount` call to handle dispatching a call to your redux actions. Just remember to import the actions you need above.

```
const store = configureStore();

export default class Index extends Component {
  componentWillMount = () => {
      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
          const { nav: { routes } } = store.getState();
          const currentRouteName = routes[routes.length-1].routeName;

          if (currentRouteName === 'EditCoupleProfile') {
              store.dispatch(editCoupleActions.navigateBack())
          } else if ( currentRouteName === 'EditInterests' ) {
              store.dispatch(interestsActions.navigateBack())
          } else {
              store.dispatch(popFromStack());
          }
          return true;
      })
  };

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress');
  };

  render() {
      return (
          <Provider store={store}>
              <AppWithNavigation />
          </Provider>
      );
   }
}
```